# Universal cell for UITableView and UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, uicollectionview

I was wondering if there are some best practices for implementing universal cell which can be used with both of `UITableView` and `UICollectionView`...

I tried to put `UITableViewCell` into CollectionView but Xcode complained about this. I have just one variant left: make `UIView` which will implement cell's view and then implement `UITableViewCell` and `UICollectionViewCell` subclasses which will wrap this custom `UIView` so it could be placed into Table/Colleciton view. Is that the right way to achieve my goal?

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: no that is not..

Comment: your idea is ok, but you should be careful with layout.

Comment: please try & also let us know if you are able to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea can be implemented if the UIView's subviews are similar.You can make a template of `UIView`,create multiple widgets inside it,and create instance in `UITableViewCell` and `UICollectionViewCell`,as `UITableViewCell` and `UICollectionViewCell` are usually reused, you need to separate the data model and views,so realize your idea.